# How to use arrays in Python similar to how they're used in matlab

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matlab

I'm currently trying to improve my python skills by using it to recreate some old matlab projects I did in undergrad. I once used matlab to simulate a proton attracting an electron, using multidimensional arrays to store the positions and velocities for each time step. Now I'm trying to do the same thing in Python, but the way in which arrays work is very different from the way they're used in matlab. I'm running into a lot of errors and figuring things out as I go, but I think I'm stuck thinking about arrays in the "matlab way" and some points on how to accomplish this in python would be greatly appreciated.

```
#This code is for plotting the trajectory of an electron travelling through space
#The particle is in the vacinity of a central force (A proton at the origin)

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

re = np.array([[1e-11],[1e-11]]) #let re denote the trajectory of the electron with x = r[0] and y = r[1]
m = 9.11e-31 #mass of electron
k = 8.99e9 #Coulomb's constant [N m^2/C^2]
q = 1.6e-19 #charge of electron and proton [C]
rp = [0,0] #rp is the position of the proton
dt = 0.001 #time differential [s]

v = np.array([[-3e12],[0]]) #the electron has initial velocity of v = (-3, 0) [m/s]
phi = np.arctan2(re[1][0], re[0][0]) #starting angle

for i in range(1,10):
   # nrex = (re[0][i-1])+v[0][i-1]*dt #nuew position in x
   # nrey = (re[1][i-1])+v[1][i-1]*dt #new position in y
    re[0] = np.append(re[0], ((re[0][i-1])+v[1][i-1]*dt), axis=1) #, axis=1) #for each timestep move the velocity in x
    re[1] = np.append(re[1], ((re[1][i-1])+v[1][i-1]*dt), axis=1) #for each timestep mobe the velocity in y

    phi = np.arctan2(re[1][i],re[0][i]) #update the angle
    rho = np.sqrt(re[0][i]**2 + re[1][i]**2) #update separation from proton
    v[0] = np.append(n[0], (v[0][i-1]+((k*(q**2)/(rho**2))/m)*np.cos(phi)*dt), axis=1) #update velocity in x
    v[1] = np.append(v[1], (v[1][i-1]+((k*(q**2)/(rho**2))/m)*np.sin(phi)*dt), axis=1) #update velocity in y
    
plt.scatter(re[0][:], re[1][:], s=2, c='b') #Plot electron's trajectory
plt.scatter(rp[0],rp[1], s=3, c='r') #Show proton's position
plt.show() #Show
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is add the next "state" of the system at the end of every "vector" within an array (one for position and one for velocity, both containing  components for x and y), and finally plotting each time state to see the entire trajectory. This however returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\hecto\OneDrive\Documentos\ITESM\8vo semestre\Repaso Python\ParticleInElectricField.py", line 20, in <module>    
    re[0] = np.append(re[0], ((re[0][i-1])+v[1][i-1]*dt), axis=1) #, axis=1) #for each timestep move the velocity in x
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in append
  File "C:\Users\hecto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 5499, in append
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in concatenate
numpy.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
PS C:\Users\hecto\OneDrive\Documentos\ITESM\8vo semestre\Repaso Python>
```

Can you not append to a specific "vector" within an array? Or am I missing something. Any pointers help, thanks in advance!

When I tried the same code withoue the "axis=1" i returned an erro about the dimensions of the array. This is probably because without it, np.append flattens the vector. When I try "axis=0", the error becomes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\hecto\OneDrive\Documentos\ITESM\8vo semestre\Repaso Python\ParticleInElectricField.py", line 20, in <module>
    re[0] = np.append(re[0], ((re[0][i-1])+v[1][i-1]*dt), axis=0) #, axis=1) #for each timestep move the velocity in x
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in append
  File "C:\Users\hecto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 5499, in append        
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 
1 has 0 dimension(s)
```

This is weird because what I'm trying to append is a value, not an array. It makes sense that it has dimension 0, but why would it need to have a dimension to be appended to the end of the array? This makes me think that the "axis=0" is the wrong way to go, but I couldn't tell you why either.

Comment: Stay away from `np.append`.  It's a poorly named imitation of the list append.  As you can see from the error it is just calling `np.concatenate`.  Don't use either repeatedly in a loop; build a list instead.  Imitating MATLAB is not a good way to learn `numpy`.  There is a `np.matrix` subclass that was intended for wayward MATLAB users, with only 2d arrays.  But that dates back to MATLAB 3.5 days.

Comment: It may help to look at the code for `np.append`.  Without `axis` it flattens the inputs (or makes a scalar a 1d array), and joins them.  With `axis` it just does `concatenate`, which has specific rules about matching the number of dimenssions etc.

Comment: An important difference.  MATLAB dimension is always 2 (or higher).  `numpy` can be 0d, 1d, etc.MATLAB'scalars have size (1,1).  Python has true scalars, which may become 0d arrays  MATLAB does a lot of jit, so iteration doesn't hurt performance much. `numpy` works best with compiled whole-array methods.  Python level iteration is slow.

Comment: Since you aren't doing an array calculations, you could use 'plain' python lists, and `math` module functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
re = np.array([[1e-11],[1e-11]])
```

`re` starts as a (2,1) array.

```
....

v = np.array([[-3e12],[0]])
```

another (2,1) array.

```
phi = np.arctan2(re[1][0], re[0][0])
```

You can index `re[1,0]`.  It's more idiomatic.

```
for i in range(1,10):
   ....
    re[0] = np.append(re[0], ((re[0][i-1])+v[1][i-1]*dt), axis=1) #, axis=1)
```

You try to concatenate a (1,) shape to scalar, `re[0,i-1]` etc.

With axis=1, it complains `numpy.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1`  (python indexing is [0,n)).

With axis=0, it complains:

```
return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 
1 has 0 dimension(s)
```

Note, `append` has passed the action on to `concatenate`.  That in turn requires that all inputs have the same number of dimensions.  You gave it a mix of 1d and 0d.

It doesn't get to the point of doing:

```
re[0] = ...
```

You can't 'grow' an array, or row of an array by assignment.  MATLAB allows such growth, making a new matrix under the covers etc.  `numpy` arrays can't 'grow'.  `concatenate` makes a new array, copying values.

```
...  
    phi = np.arctan2(re[1,i],re[0,i])
    rho = np.sqrt(re[0,i]**2 + re[1,i]**2)
```

Since you haven't added columns to `re`, this `i` and `[i-1]` indexing doesn't do anything meaningful.

To do this iteratively either start with

```
re = np.zeros((10,2))   # or
re = np.zeros((2,10))
```

or

```
relist = []
```

Then at each step you can either

```
re[i,0 ] = new values
re[0,i] = ...
```

or

```
relist.append(new values)
```

with a `re = np.array(relist)` at the end.

Python lists are designed for (relatively) efficient growth; arrays are not.

Stepping through rows of an array is little more natural in `numpy`, since the trailing dimensions are inner most (reverse of MATLAB).  In theory either works.

---

If you need to stick to growing the (2,1) array to (2,2), then (2,3), etc, you need to `concatenate` an (2,1) array with axis=1. In other words, concatenate (2,n) with (2,1) to get (2,n+1).

With lists it is simpler to `append` a 2 element list each step.  At the end you'll get a list of lists, which becomes a (n,2) array, one row per iteration.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response! It has been very helpful.